# Template 10 scrolling hamburger menu

Tags: uwp, template10, hamburger-menu

I have an Template 10 hamburger menu with PrimaryButtons and a SecondaryButton.
In the PrimaryButtons I have three HamburgerButtonInfo with ButtonType="Literal". The first has a Stackpanel with user information the second one a ListView with 5 entries and the third has a ListView with many entries. Now my whole PrimaryButtons are scrollable because the last ListView is to long.
My goal is to make the first two HamburgerButtonInfos visible (sticky) all the time and the last one is scrollable.
Any ideas?

UPDATE: XamlCode

```
<Controls:HamburgerMenu x:Name="MyHamburgerMenu">
    <Controls:HamburgerMenu.PrimaryButtons>
        <!-- account data -->
        <Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo ButtonType="Literal" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Width="38" Height="38" Margin="5" Source="../Assets/ProfilePlaceholder.png" />
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.Account.UserName, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="18" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.Account.PrimaryAddress, Mode=OneWay}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" FontSize="16" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
                <Line StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="#cacaca" X2="300" Margin="10,5" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo>

        <!-- standard folder -->
        <Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo ButtonType="Literal">
            <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.StandardFolderList, Mode=OneWay}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Type, Converter={StaticResource FolderTypeToImageSourceConverter}}" Width="19" Height="19" Margin="0,0,20,0" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo>

        <!-- user folder -->
        <Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo ButtonType="Literal">
            <StackPanel x:Name="UserFolderListView">
                <TextBlock Text="Folders" FontSize="14" Foreground="#8f8f8f" Margin="5" Visibility="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.UserFolderList, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ValueNotNullToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                <toolkit:TreeView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.UserFolderList, Mode=OneWay}" Background="#fafafa">
                    <toolkit:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Counter}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <data:DataTemplateExtensions.Hierarchy>
                                <data:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ChildFolder}" />
                            </data:DataTemplateExtensions.Hierarchy>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </toolkit:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                </toolkit:TreeView>
            </StackPanel>
        </Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo>
    </Controls:HamburgerMenu.PrimaryButtons>

    <Controls:HamburgerMenu.SecondaryButtons>
        <!--  settingspage button  -->
        <Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo x:Name="SettingsButton" PageParameter="0"
                                      PageType="views:SettingsPage">
            <Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo.NavigationTransitionInfo>
                <SuppressNavigationTransitionInfo />
            </Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo.NavigationTransitionInfo>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <SymbolIcon Width="48" Height="48"
                            Symbol="Setting" />
                <TextBlock Margin="12,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Text="Settings" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo>
    </Controls:HamburgerMenu.SecondaryButtons>

</Controls:HamburgerMenu>
```

thanx

Comment: Please show your xaml code.

Comment: have you checked my answer? Is this an accept one?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Live Visual Tree` to check the layout of `HamburgerMenu`, you can see that in the Content area of `PrimaryButtons`, there is a `ScrollViewer` inside it:
[image]

It means, the content inside of this area will have infinitive size, so when you scroll it, you actually scroll this `ScrollViewer`, not your `ListView`, this is why your first two elements will disappear when you scroll it.

To make a `ListView` vertical-scroll-able, it must have a finite height, in this scenario, I suggest you to give a fixed `Height` to your `ListView`. And from what I see, your third one is a `TreeView`, that is the same, `StackPanel` also has infinitive size, you can either give a size to your `StackPanel` named "UserFolderListView", or give a height to its child `TreeView`.

In case you also want to make the layout adapt to different size of device, you can use [VisualStateManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to give different heights when target on different devices.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an easy way to do what you are asking without some significant visual tree crawling. If you don't mind doing that, then here's the idea. Find the `ScrollViewer` automatically used by the Primary buttons and set it's `verticalScrollMode` to `Disabled`. This gets you half way there. This causes the Primary buttons to stop scrolling. We would never add this as a common property to the HamMenu because this is very edge case. But at least you can do it.

The second part is to use a single literal. With a single literal, you can fill the remaining space with a `Grid` with two rows. The first row will have your two stationary items - which you are no responsible for managing (the cost of this type of customization but, also, not the end of the world). The second row can hold your `ListView` which will then scroll appropriately like you are asking.

I want to reiterate that this is an edge case that the control will never support out of the box. That being said, I think this should work perfectly for you. PLEASE, if you are willing, once you set this approach up, post some code back in this question so future developers can benefit from your effort.

Best of luck!